# Element ignore is not allowed here, in Android lint.xml

Tags: android, xml, lint

I'm currently working on reducing the lint warnings/errors in my Android project. I'm fixing as many as possible, but some don't apply to my project and others come from 3rd party libraries etc.

So I'm setting up some lint rules in a `lint.xml` file within my `app/` so that it gets automatically picked up.

Here's a cut down version of my lint file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
    <issue id="UnusedResources">
        <ignore regexp=".*google-services.*" />
    </issue>
</lint>
```

Now these lint rules are picked up correctly and work, but Android Studio is syntax highlighting `ignore` red, and saying "Element ignore is not allowed here", the same is true of all the ignore tags in this xml file.

Can anyone help me get rid of this annoying red?

Comment: same issue [here](https://i.imgur.com/q1CmwXu.png), never had this before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is described here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=200884

It is fixed in Android Studio 2.2, which was released today!

Comment: Thanks, I can confirm that upgrading has fixed this!